# updating plugin from qgis 2 to 3. qRegisterResourceData . argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, migration

I already followed this tutorial and been through the steps. 
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/wiki/Plugin-migration-to-QGIS-3 
 and https://gisforthought.com/updating-a-plugin-from-qgis-2-to-qgis-3/

I make some changes and started to track down the last errors. But im lost with this one:

```
TypeError: qRegisterResourceData(int, bytes, bytes, bytes): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
```

I have the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 336, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/Lars/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\_plugin\__init__.py", line 5, in classFactory
    from ._plugin_TEST import _plugin_TEST
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 664, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Lars/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\_plugin\_plugin_TEST.py", line 28, in 
    from . import resources
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 664, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Lars/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\_plugin\resources.py", line 85, in 
    qInitResources()
  File "C:/Users/Lars/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\_plugin\resources.py", line 80, in qInitResources
    QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)
TypeError: qRegisterResourceData(int, bytes, bytes, bytes): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'


Python version: 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.0.0-Girona Girona, 001c80b0c3
```

Any leads or solutions?

Comment: I am also having the same error. The command below is showing the error
...\apps\Python36\Scripts\pyrcc5.bat -o resources.py resources.qrc ERROR Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec) File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyrcc_main.py", line 21, in <module> from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR, QDir, QFile
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified mod

Answer (score 3):

Your "resources.py"  presumably is for python2.
You must generate a new file for python3

For example Windows: `...\apps\Python36\Scripts\pyrcc5.bat -o resources.py resources.qrc`