# TypeError: qRegisterResourceData(int, bytes, bytes, bytes): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-2, pyqt5, pyqt4

Similar question here, I tried the suggested answer but it didn't work for my situation.
[updating plugin from qgis 2 to 3. qRegisterResourceData . argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276540/updating-plugin-from-qgis-2-to-3-qregisterresourcedata-argument-2-has-unexpec)
I am trying to migrate a plugin to QGIS3 using qgis2to3 and I got stuck on an error;
TypeError: qRegisterResourceData(int, bytes, bytes, bytes): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
It seems that when I run the pyrcc5.bat I get a new resources.py but not a new resources.qrc, should have I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what I managed to come up with that ended up working for me;
in the OSgeo4W Shell I ran; 04w_env, qt5_env, and py3_env then I cd'd to where my plugin folder was, then ran pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources_rc.py and that got me past this error.